# A question from a test in statistics?

Tags: regression, variance, expected-value, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I got the following question in my finals, but the teacher claims I didn't answer this right, I chose `a.` as the right answer, what is the right answer and why?

Here is the question:

In a research about the connection between two quantitative  variables there were collected observations (more than 2), where each observation has value for `x` and `y` and the standard deviation of `x` and `y` ,$S_x$ $S_y$, greater than `0`.

which one of the following is true:

1. if Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient is $1$ then
   Spearman's rank correlation coefficient isn't necessarily 1.
2. if $S_x = S_y$ then $\mathrm{Cov}(x,y)$ can't be greater than $S_x$.
3. if $\mathrm{Cov}(x,y) = 0$ then the  percentage of variance **non** explained
   must be `0`.
4. if the regression line's slope of expected $y$ value as function of
   $x$ is 1, then the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient is
   $1$.

Comment: Did the teacher tell you which one was meant to be correct?

Comment: @mark999 I think all of them are wrong...

Comment: In response to your flag, I don't think this question belongs on math.SE. In case you are not happy with current suggestions, you can always offer a bounty to attract users' attention.

Comment: I edited the existing answer to emphasize how it fully answers the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**None are correct.**

The first is wrong because Spearman's rank correlation is defined the Pearson correlation using ranks instead of actual values: therefore when the Spearman correlation is not $1$, the Pearson correlation cannot be $1$, either.

In the second answer the covariance and $S_x$ are measured in different units and so are not even comparable.

In the third answer the percentage of variance **explained** must be 0.

In the fourth answer, the regression slope is not related to the value of Pearson's correlation coefficient. The PCC can be any value between $0$ and $1$ (not including $0$) and when the slope is $1$ the slope can be any positive value when the PCC is $1$

Comment: It holds for variance not standard deviation

Comment: Yes, then it seems that all are false

Comment: If $Y = aX + b$, then $a=r\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$, where $r$ is the Pearson correlation, $\sigma_{X,Y}$ are the respective standard deviations.